# Every connected graph contains at least 2 vertices of the same degree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Theorem**:Every connected graph contains at least 2 vertices of the same degree. (In the Finite and Simple Graph Context)

What can I do to prove ? Can you give me any suggestion ?

Comment: You don't need "connected" but you do need "finite" and "simple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let the graph have $n$ vertices. As the graph is connected, no vertex can have degree $0$. If a given vertex is adjacent to every other vertex, its degree is $n-1$ and that is the maximum possible degree for a vertex in a $n$-vertex graph.

The degrees can thus take values from $1$ to $n-1$.

Use the Pigeon Hole principle.